# How can I update an object in a nested array when an input value changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a list of articles, each with some number of exercises, and each exercise has a duration property. The duration property is editable, but I can't seem to figure out how to update this so it takes effect in my original array.

I've setup a [basic example](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-maxwell-71v1y?file=/src/EditDuration.js) in CodeSandbox.

Expected behavior is when changing one of the input fields, it should update in my articles array (which is located in App.js)

I'm trying to do: `onChange={(e) => setDuration(e.target.value)}`

As I see it, the problem is that React doesn't like if you change the current state, so I would have to create a new state... So this "new" duration should somehow propagate to App.js maybe? Or is the solution to have a method in App.js that you pass down all components to update the original array?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please provide more of your code here in your question. It's not adequate to link out to it.

Comment: The issue is, you are updating the state of the child component which ends up going through the rerender cycle, but not the parent, as the rerenders are only pushed top down, not bottom up, so the parent's state has not been changed and thus, you don't see any changes in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the state in the app itself doesn't change the object the app received.

you'll need to manually change the object

try adding:

```
const onChange = (e)=>{
    exercise.duration = e.target.value;
    setDuration(e.target.value)
}
```

and change your
onChange={(e) => setDuration(e.target.value)}

to:

```
onChange={onChange}
```

NOTE: this wont cause the parent to rerender.

Comment: This still doesnt seem to change the array in App.js ? It changes in the component, but it still doesnt seem to take effect in App.js -> https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-payne-3d86j?file=/src/EditDuration.js

Comment: Update: 

This still doesnt seem to change the array in App.js ? It changes in the component, but it still doesnt seem to take effect in App.js -> https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-payne-3d86j?file=/src/EditDuration.js - Why is that? If I add a save button in App.js and log out the articles, I can see the array is changed, but it isn't reflected in App.js when outputting the array in the DOM, and what if I wanted to have App.js re-render when changing the duration for each component ?

Comment: its because it didnt rerender, if you want to make it rerender, you can pass a setState function to a child, and call it there.